# Remove all blocks from Magento template

Tags: php, magento-layout-xml, magento

I want to remove all default blocks from the template/layout file of my custom Magento module. Currently I have used individual removes like

```
<module_cart_index>
   <remove name="head" />
   <remove name="header" />
   <remove name="footer" />
   <remove name="right"/>
   <remove name="left"/>
   <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
   <remove name="checkout.cart" />
   <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar" />
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="cp.cart" template="module/cart.phtml" />
    </reference>
</module_cart_index>
```

I want that the output from `cart.phtml` should not contain any code from Magento but it should only contain the code written in it.

Right now when I run `http://127.0.0.1/mag/index.php/module/cart/` it outputs a complete `HTML` page with `<html>, <head>, <body>` and all other tags. How can I remove these tags?
I want to get only the content written on `module/cart.phtml`.

Is there any way to remove/prevent the default layout rendering in Magento?

Comment: Hey Arvind. Did you ever found a solution for this? Im having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a **json response**, you can just echo it from controller.
If you are trying something else, this should help you:

1. create a `blank.phtml` in your template's page folder. This file should have at least this line:

   `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>`
2. in your layout put this code:

`<module_cart_index>`

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/blank.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="checkout/cart" name="cp.cart" template="module/cart.phtml" />
</reference>
```

`</module_cart_index>`

Comment: There is not `blank.phtml` available? `empty.phtml` is there. When I used `empty.phtml`, it showed the same page with all `HTML` content. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I said create it and put in it just that line.

Comment: Created it. Still the same effect. Getting full fledged HTML page. Although sidebars and other blocks are not present, but its still an HTML page :(

Comment: Can you set display blocks and template paths from admin and write here the output?

Comment: In your controller add this line at the end, it will help you with debug `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());`

Comment: I will try this and then tell you:)

Answer (score 0):

This is how Magento does it, in *app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/api2.xml*:

```
<adminhtml_api2_role_grid>
    <remove name="root"/>
    <block type="api2/adminhtml_roles_grid" name="api2_roles.grid" output="toHtml"/>
</adminhtml_api2_role_grid>
```

So to get this to work with your custom block, do something like this:

```
<some_layout_handle>
    <remove name="root"/>
    <block type="customextension/block_name" template="some-template.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
</some_layout_handle>
```

This works for me, the only content output is what my template/block generates. I assume the block might have to extend *Mage_Core_Block_Template* for this to actually work.